# Align-items causing layout issue for grid-box nested inside a flex-box on Safari

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

On Google Chrome the following is not an issue. However, when using Safari for MacOS (not sure about Windows and not sure about mobile), the `.element`s inside the flex container are being positioned incorrectly and completely outside of the container element itself. When I remove `align-items: center` the issue goes away. However, I need `align-items: center` for my layout to be correct. Please help.

Here is an image of what I am seeing on Safari vs what I want and am seeing on Chrome:

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.element {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1rem 1rem auto 1rem;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  border: 0.05rem solid black;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="element">
    <span>X</span>
    <span>Y</span>
    <div class="content">
      <span>Element one content</span>
      <span>Element one more content</span>
    </div>
    <span>Z</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="element">
    <span>X</span>
    <span>Y</span>
    <div class="content">
      <span>Element two content</span>
      <span>Element two more content</span>
    </div>
    <span>Z</span>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Consider setting a `height` to `.container`. Percentage heights need a reference point on the parent. The `.element { height: 100% }` shouldn't work, but maybe it does on Chrome or Safari as an [intervention](https://github.com/WICG/interventions). In any case, for more details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276).

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you are using the latest version of safari. The older version did have some flexbox bugs.

Comment: I am on Version 17.2.1 (19617.1.17.11.12)

Comment: I think this can be a comment.